# Multiple HD video streaming using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to stream HD rtsp streams (1080p) from IPcamera over LAN and displaying it.
streaming is done using openRTSP and decoding is done using ffmpeg.
For a single frame decoding takes 30-40ms and displaying it on the QTwindow takes another 6-7 ms. When streaming more than 2-3 cameras the whole system is not able to handle it.Can anybody tell me that what could be the best method to approach the problem. Right now I am using a machine with Pentium 64-bit  processor with ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Should I go for Graphics card ? If so which would be better for ffmpeg hardware acceleration ?
If I have to display 16 videos, Will one graphics card sufficient ?

Comment: To clarify, you are encoding 16 streams and are having trouble, or decoding?

Comment: I am trying to decode 16 streams. I want suggestions to go in proper direction. To decode and display 1080p of 16 streams what kind of GPU I can use with ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few methods.

First is to lower the number of frames decoded - either by lowering the frame rate on the encoder side, or to decode only keyframes and skip the rest.

Second is to increase the decoding power - add CPUs or add decoding hardware. AFAIK a graphics card can only decode one h264 stream at a time; not sure if this is the software or hardware restriction. So you're unlikely to gain much here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can anybody please tell, how NVRs are handling and displaying multiple HD videos. It seems like there is way but I am not aware of it.

Comment: At least one of them provides the downscaled streams to the console (like 320x240 or so) while storing the full HD on disk, and only switches to streaming the full HD when this specific stream is maximized. The downscaled stream doesn't even have to be h264, so the decoding requirements might be even less tight.